# Add code intelligence to rest api links in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I have nodejs app that listens to rest call being made to it. However, i want to add some intelligence to my code.

For instance i only want to execute a function for a given call every 5 minutes. So even if someone calls the rest link every second or minute i only want to execute it every 5 minutes. How do i achieve such flexibility ?

Random calls to the nodejs server

```
http:// abc.com/pager/a     is called 100 times within 5 minutes should only execute the function once for the first call and must resume executing the function after 5 minutes 
http:// abc.com/pager/b
http:// abc.com/pager/c
```

Sample Code

```
app.post('/pager/:room',function(req,res){

var room = req.params.room;

if( room == 'a'){
    console.log("Room A called");
    //execute function once every 5 minutes only for room a  
    func1(room)
}

else if( room == 'b'){
    console.log("Room B called");
    //execute function once every 5 minutes only for room b
    func1(room)
}

else if( room == 'c'){
    console.log("Room C called");
    //execute function once every 5 minutes only for room c
    func1(room)
}


});
```

Comment: If I understood the question correctly you need to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setInterval).

Comment: @razvan If i use setInterval that will call it  after fixed time delay. In my case i don't know when the rest call will be made. I just want to maintain a case were if a function is already executed and subsequent calls to execute it is within 5 minutes of interval i don't want that call to execute it.

Comment: If what you want is to block the function from getting re-run more often than every 5 minutes, (ie. if two users go to http:// abc.com/pager/a only a minute apart from one another, and you only the first call will run, until at least 5 minutes has elapsed) .. then you need to store this timing information someplace globally accessible to all users, probably in a database. Store the timestamp when you started the first call in the database, then on subsequent calls check that timestamp to see if n-minutes has elapsed, and if not, exit

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic function returns another function that disables itself for a specified number of ms after it has been called.

```js
function tempDisableAfterCall(fn, ms) {
  var timeToReset = 0;

  return function() {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (currentTime < timeToReset) {
      return;
    } else {
      timeToReset = currentTime + ms;
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
}

// Function that will be temporarily disabled
function printNumber(num) {
  console.log(num)
}

// Create a modified function that is disabled after it has been called
var printNumberWait = tempDisableAfterCall(printNumber, 5000);

// Call the function every 500 ms, but you will only see a log every 5 seconds
setInterval(function() {
  printNumberWait(new Date().getTime());
}, 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example of how you can accomplish only running the function no more often than once every 5 minutes no matter how frequently the endpoint is called.

```
app.set('roomFunctionActive', false);

app.post('/pager/:room',function(req,res){

  var room = req.params.room;

  var roomFunctionActive = app.get('roomFunctionActive');   

  if(!roomFunctionActive) {

      app.set('roomFunctionActive', true);

      func1(room);

      setTimeout(function() {
          app.set('roomFunctionActive', false);
      }, 300000);

  }

});
```

Of course, the **roomFunctionActive** could be changed to be a different variable for each room ('a', 'b', 'c') allowing each rooms function to run once every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

A redis instance would be a good solution, you can set a key value pair and also set it to expire after 5 mins.

Check to see if the key value pair exists, if not then execute your function and set a new key/value pair with a 5 min expiry time.

It might be overkill but you could even use a module called redis-sessions which create time limited tokens especially for this kind of purpose

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-sessions